# pyqt5 how to fix image size in VBox?

Tags: python, pyqt5

i created image with label in VBox but the issue is the size of the image is not same as the VBox size.

when i tried to fix it the image goes to the right

this is my code:-

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
import requests

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Image")
        self.resize(1274, 906)
        self.ititUI()
    def ititUI(self):
        self.anime = QWidget(self)
        self.anime.move(20, 20)
        self.vAnime = QVBoxLayout(self.anime)
        self.anime.setFixedSize(272, 456)
        self.anime.setObjectName("anime")
        self.limage = QLabel(self)
        image = QImage()
        image.loadFromData(requests.get('https://64.media.tumblr.com/853aebaad6d38097da49e8986b8458b9/tumblr_odewby7Kr51szm930o1_1280.jpg').content)
        self.limage.setPixmap(QPixmap(image))
        self.limage.setScaledContents(True)
        self.limage.setFixedSize(272, 384)
        self.lname = QLabel("Image Text",self)
        self.lname.setWordWrap(True)
        self.lname.setObjectName('lname')
        self.vAnime.addWidget(self.limage)
        self.vAnime.addWidget(self.lname)
        self.lname.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignTop)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet(open("style.stylesheet", "r").read())
win = MyWindow()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: "the image is not same as the VBox size." -> what do you mean? Do you want to set the image as background?

Comment: i wanna make the image size as the VBox size
when i make it the same size it's goes to the right a little bit

Comment: I'd say you could use `self.vAnime.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)` (see [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins)), but be aware that your implementation is absolutely *wrong* for two reasons: the `self.anime` widget should be set as the *central widget* of the main window (using `setCentralWidget()`), and no blocking function (such as `requests.get()`) should **ever** happen in the main Qt thread.

Comment: thank you alot ♥ for answering my question thats fix my issue and i'm sorry for comment to late